# "Stack around the variable 's' was corrupted." when writing to a binary file

Tags: c, stack

I wrote a code which reads from a binary file and then updates it by writing at the end of the file one more object of type "STUDENT". However, upon entering from the keyboard the last variable, the "Stack around the variable 's' was corrupted." error pops up. If I ignore it, the code seems to do what it's supposed to.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
 
typedef struct {
    int nrmat;
    char nume[30];
    char an;
    int grp;
    char tip;
    struct {
        char zi;
        char luna;
        int an;
    } data;
    struct {
        char oraint;
        char minutint;
    } intrare;
    struct {
        char oraies;
        char minuties;
    } iesire;
} STUDENT;
 
void sosire(const char* nume) {
    FILE* f;
    STUDENT s;
    f = fopen(nume, "r+b");
    if (!f)
        printf("\nFisierul nu a putut fi deschis.");
    else {
        fread(&s, sizeof(STUDENT), 1, f);
        while (!feof(f))
            fread(&s, sizeof(STUDENT), 1, f);
        
        printf("\nSosire student:\n");
        printf("Nr. matricol: ");
        scanf("%d", &s.nrmat);
        printf("Nume student: ");
        scanf("%s", &s.nume);
        printf("An: ");
        scanf("%d", &s.an);
        printf("Grupa: ");
        scanf("%d", &s.grp);
        printf("Tip (Biblioteca <'B'> sau Laboratoare <'L'>: ");
        scanf("%s", &s.tip);
        printf("Data\nZi: ");
        scanf("%d", &s.data.zi);
        printf("Luna: ");
        scanf("%d", &s.data.luna);
        printf("An: ");
        scanf("%d", &s.data.an);
        printf("Ora sosire\nOra: ");
        scanf("%d", &s.intrare.oraint);
        printf("Minute: ");
        scanf("%d", &s.intrare.minutint);
 
        fwrite(&s, sizeof(STUDENT), 1, f);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
 
int main() {
    sosire((const char*)"SecvStud.dat");
    return 0;
}
```

I tried reading the name of the student using `fgets(s.nume, 30, stdin)` thinking it would help but the error still occurred.

Comment: Not causing your error, but you should remove the `&` from `scanf("%s", &s.nume);`. An array already decays to a pointer. And you should use a length limit: `scanf("%29s", s.nume);`. That might cause issues but if you also get this error with `fgets` then this is probably not the reason.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &s.tip);` What do you want to input here? `tip` is a single character. It cannot hold any string.

Comment: Did you get any compiler warnings? Most of your `scanf`s are wrong.

Comment: OT: `sosire((const char*)"SecvStud.dat");` -> `sosire("SecvStud.dat");`, the cast is useless.

Comment: OT: mixing `scanf` and `fgets` is usually a bad idea.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &s.data.luna);` You cannot read an integer value into a `char` variable. This will write 4 bytes (on most machines) instead of 1 byte. Either use some temporary `int` variable or use `%hhd`

Comment: General note: You should check the return values of all IO functions. `fopen`, `fread`, `fwrite`, `scanf`. If `fopen` returns `NULL` you will feed that into `fclose`

Comment: You switched *what*? There are multiple hints in comments and most apply to multiple lines in your code.

Comment: Probably better to `fopen( filename, "ab" );` and not muck with reading records to reach the end of the file...

Comment: Are the `char` variables supposed to carry numerical values or characters? If you'd like them to carry numerical information, it'd be clearer to use `int8_t`. Not that it helps the current situation, but still.

Comment: @Gerhardh used "%hhd" and it fixed the error. Thank you!

Comment: Questions about non english code are usually harder to answer. What is the meaning of following fields: an, grp, tip, zi, luna, an, oraint, minutint, oraies and minuties? If we knew what these field are supposed to represent, then we can tell you more.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the other suggestions as well, posted this in a rush and that's why the variable names are not in English, I'm grateful for you bearing with me though.

Comment: Note: If you switch to `int8_t` (from `<stdint.h>`) then use `"%" SCNd8` in `scanf` (from `<inttypes.h>`.